# Rails 3 , Simple search form problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Code in my product model (product.rb):

```
   def self.search(search)
    if search
     find(:all)
    else
     find(:all)
    end
  end
```

Code in my search controller (search_controller.rb):

```
  def index
    @products = Product.search("Apple")
  end
```

Code in my view (index.html.erb):

```
<h1>Products</h1>

<% form_tag client_search_path , :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= search_field_tag :term, params[:term], :class=> "auto_search_complete"%>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'button', :id => "search_bn" %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Quantity available</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Shopcenter name</th>
    <th>Shopcenter streetnumb</th>
    <th>Shopcenter streetname</th>
    <th>Shopcenter postal</th>
    <th>Shopcenter province</th>
  </tr>

<% for product in @products%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.brand %></td>
    <td><%= product.quantity_available %></td>
    <td><%= product.category %></td>
    <td><%= product.shopCenter_name %></td>
    <td><%= product.shopCenter_streetNumb %></td>
    <td><%= product.shopCenter_streetName %></td>
    <td><%= product.shopCenter_postal %></td>
    <td><%= product.shopCenter_province %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I load this all is good, but if I comment one of the line of codes in my model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
     #find(:all)
    else
     find(:all)
    end
  end
```

I expect this to work also at least for the initial render, or when I submit an empty search term, but it's not. And changing the code to of the model to:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
     find_all_by_name(search)
    else
     find(:all)
    end
  end
```

Doesn't work it gives me an error that the view is working with a nil object, which is impossible because my database has entries.

Can someone explain what is going on? I have the impression that both the conditions in my model are being executed. At least that's what 2 puts statement in each case showed me.
Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had some compatibility issues with Rails 3.

I updated rails and ruby and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set search = nil if search == "" in your controller otherwise it will always go to the first condition.

Comment: in your controller @products = Product.search("Apple") should be 
@products = Product.search(params[:term]) and in your Model
before you do the if, 
search = nil if search == ""